# redirect to .bak file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to do a redirect to a .bak file on an iis server with framework 4.0, but when i do the redirect to "download" the file, it just says "server is not found error 404." How can i fix this?

I have set the mime type on mi iis thinking this is the problem, but im having no luck what else can i do?

this is all i do:

```
Response.Redirect("http file");
```

i had no problems uploading it, but im having trouble download.

Comment: Are you sure the download path is correct?

Comment: Are you using routing?

Comment: not sure what do you mean with routing, but im sure the file is there you can try by yourself [link](adsertidocs.dev.adserti.mx/Documentos/0004/AdsertiTask/Evidencias/ID-10230.bak)

Comment: Is `Response.Redirect("http file");` your actual code? You should post your actual code.

Comment: Is your IIS permitted to serve files with a ".bak" extension?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".